# django-tables2 LinkColumn show Date correctly

Tags: python, django-tables2, django-1.11

I'm currently working on a project using Django 1.11.2 with django-tables2. I use a table to display my model. The model has a DateTimeField, which is displayed correctly in a normal column but when I use a LinkColumn with this DateTimeField, the dates are displayed in a complex format like this: '2017-02-23 07:49:53.067504+00:00' instead of '23.02.2017 07:49'.
The links work fine but I can't find a way to get back to the simple format.

[image: The LinkColumn looks like this]

My model in models.py:

```
class mymodel(models.Model):
Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, help_text='(Format: TT.MM.JJJJ)')

...other fields...

class Meta:
    ordering = ["Date"]
    verbose_name = "MyModel"
    verbose_name_plural = "MyModels"
```

and the table:

```
class MyModelTable(django_tables2.Table):
Date = django_tables2.LinkColumn(viewname='MyModelView', kwargs={"id": Accessor("id")})
class Meta:
    model = MyModel
    exclude = {'id'}
    attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}
```

Thanks in advance for any help or ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`LinkColumn`](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#linkcolumn) converts the value in the column to string and doesn't care about dates. You can use the `text` argument to `LinkColumn` to pass a callable to use render the value in a custom way.

For example:

```
class MyModelTable(django_tables2.Table):
    Date = django_tables2.LinkColumn(
        viewname='MyModelView', 
        kwargs={"id": Accessor("id")},
        text=lambda record: record.Date.strftime('%x %X')
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = {'id'}
```

Will render both date and time using format string `%x %X`, [documentation here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Note that if this field is nullable, you should add a check for that in the callable you pass with `text`.